# Do you need Node installed in your hosting environment for React projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am building some React apps and am starting to think about the process of hosting. I am currently with Media Temple, which is a Apache based hosting, and I am on their (gs) grid server plan, which from what I can tell doesn't support installing Node.

I just wondered, do React apps need Node on the server?

If they do, what could my alternatives hosting options be?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing universal rendering, you'll probably need a Node server to support this.

But if it's only a static one-page application, you could perfectly not install Node on your hosting environment.

Using webpack for example, you can create a single js bundle of your vendors and sources files, a css one, and an index.html, Leaving you with 3 static files.

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much. Just what I wanted to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

No, react apps doesn't require node server